# Intermittent connection between raspberry pi 3 and DELL server

Tags: networking, local-area-network, ipv4, raspbian

using

- raspbian 3 GUI with static ip 192.168.0.199
- and a DELL server running headless ubuntu 192.168.0.196
- and a RFID reader running on 192.168.0.68

All are static IP addresses

I have a python script that polls a RFID reader running on 192.168.0.68 and has pretty consistent connection. Once the python script polls and has a positive update, it will attempt to update the DELL server provided that the RFID request is not repeated for at least 5 seconds. This is to reduce too many requests sent to the server.

However, what happens is that there are intermittent loss of connection between the raspberry pi 3 and the DELL server.

The dell server also serves web pages.

When the loss of connection happens, I can still access the dell server web pages from other devices in the same network. Similarly, from the raspberry pi 3, I can also access other servers' web pages.

This is a client network setup so I don't really have much control though I can talk with the network admin.

He is sure there's no throttling involved.

However, the connection between the raspberry pi 3 and the DELL server can be intermittent sometimes.

While I am comfortable with server side scripting and linux in general, I am at a loss of how to narrow down the issue.

The network admin at the client site is now casting aspersions on the raspberry pi 3 which is newly bought.

I am unsure if that's the case.

How to narrow down the issue or replicate the problem?

All devices are running on LAN cable.

Comment: Your Pi, while a fun toy, has no place on a professional network. It is built to be *cheap*, not built to perform well or to be reliable. The network admin is right to be suspicious of it. Narrowing down the issue involves monitoring. Collect data, analyze it, fix the problem.

Comment: How do I monitor collect data analyse ?

Comment: Hire someone to help you out. This isn't a site to seek tutorials. You're a professional, right? Go research monitoring systems.

Comment: Between hiring a professional and seeking tutorials, what are my other options?

Comment: Your option is to learn about system monitoring.

Comment: Okay let me try the learning path. At the least I want to learn enough to vet the candidates on whom to hire. How should I begin?

Comment: This might sound harsh Kim, but this is a website for answering specific and tangible systems admin and network related questions, not giving advice about how to learn - that's up to you.

Comment: Harsh but fair. I can accept that.